# Editable Datagridview in Windows application using C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

[image]

The image above is of an old DOS based application. Under the column "D/C"-the user can select either D or C. On pressing Enter, the cursor goes to next column containing textBox where user can select various Ledgers. Again on column "Debit" & "Credit"  user is allowed to enter numeric data and its moves on to next new row etc.

My question is can such interface be designed using DataGridView in windows application"? I searched the Internet to find any such example using C# in windows application but without any luck.

Comment: This sounds more like a request for software project development rather than a valid SO question. Please narrow down your question, include your code and highlight the problematic part. Best regards,

Comment: Yes @Alex to some extent your are right. But i want to design such an interface but really don't know how to go ahead.No ideas coming to my mind. Anyways thanks for your kind comments